# What are the best practices of scaling small scale webservices in AWS?

Tags: aws

I've deployed an entreprise app in AWS, in the first time i was hosting it in t2.micro, the app is intensivily used in 15 minutes a day, with some light queries in work hours during the day, after performance problems (server went down for not enough RAM) during the 15 minutes operation i've upgraded EC2 and RDS to c1.medium. but this choice is not cost effective.

is there any ideas or tricks to manage such situation when computation demande changes but in small scale. to have the most cost effective solution.

Comment: This question should be migrated to ServerFault but you can use Amazon's "spot instances" to spin up more powerful servers for short periods of time.

Comment: This is probably closer to being on-topic for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) than it is here... but have you looked at the [EC2 container service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html)?